# Top 5 longest character words (with respect to length)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

Top 5 longest character words (with respect to length):

```
file = open("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Demo.TXT", mode="r", encoding="utf8")
    file = file.read().split()
    length = 0
    Longest_word = ""
    for word in file:
        if len(word) > length:

            length = len(word)
            Longest_word = word
    
    print(Longest_word, length)
```

This code is returning only one longest word, but I need the 5 longest words.

Comment: already use sorted function but now i want to do it without builtin functions

Answer (score 0):

use sorted() to sort the list by length of each string

then grab the last 5 indexes like this i think:

```
sorted(file, key=len)
file[-5:]
```

Comment: consider having 4 spaces before the code. or while editing, select all lines that needs to be in code format then click on the `{}`